# Python - Listing files in folders - path names with a variable

Tags: python, path

I'm very very new to this.  I'm using python and I want to list files in a number of different folders (using windows)

In my first go I had loads of path variables.  Each path had its own variable.  It worked but this seemed like a long winded way of doing it.  As the paths are all the same apart from the folder name, I tried this:

```
import os

folder = ["folderA", "folderB", "folderC", "folderD"]
path1 = input('//server/files/"%s"/data' % (folder))

def list_sp_files():
    for filename in os.listdir(path1):
        print path1, filename

print "reporter"
list_sp_files()
```

I understand why it doesn't work, but I don't understand how I make it work.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `input()` requests keyboard input from the user, and evaluates that input as a Python expression.  Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this perhaps?

```
folders = ["folderA", "folderB", "folderC", "folderD"]
def list_sp_files():
    for folder in folders:
        path = '//server/files/%s/data' % (folder)
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            print path, filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `path1` to something like:

```
path1 = ["//server/files/%s/data" % f for f in folder]
```

and changing `list_sp_files()` to something like:

```
def list_sp_files(path_list):
    for path in path_list:
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            print path, filename
```

and call it via

```
list_sp_files(path1)
```

Basically this answer makes the `path1` variable a list of strings with a generator expression - it creates a list by iterating through the `folder` list and for each item there, running `"//server/files/%s/data" % f`.

The changed `list_sp_files()` simply iterates through the list of paths given to it and prints all of the contents from `os.listdir()`.