# Python - Not Reading Image on Putting a File Name as Variable in Path

Tags: python, imread

I am trying to read an image in Python 2.7 using `imread`. Below is my code.

```
with open('../Caltech Data 200-2011/CUB_200_2011/images.txt') as lines:
    for ln in islice(lines,60):
        j=0
        for x in ln.split():
            if j==1:
                print x,

                #Below is the line that is causing trouble
                img = cv2.imread('../Caltech Data 200-2011/CUB_200_2011/images/"%s"' % (x))

                cv2.imshow('Image',img)
                cv2.waitKey()
            j=j+1
```

Above code is not working. When I print the variable `x`, it is printing correctly. And when I use the any actual file name instead of the variable in `imread`, it is reading the image and showing it. But on using the variable, it is not reading the image and shows below error.

```
error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:271: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there any other way to include a variable in a path given as input to `imread`?

I have tried the above code after reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065797/python-listing-files-in-folders-path-names-with-a-variable)

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question? Do you mean, "it is **not** reading the image and showing it"?

Comment: @Robᵩ Sorry I was not clear enough earlier. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have too many quotes. Try this:

```
img = cv2.imread('../Caltech Data 200-2011/CUB_200_2011/images/%s' % (x))
```